# Lua: colon and dot function invocation acting differently

Tags: lua

I initially came across this while developing my game in LOVE2D, and I can't figure out why.
As much as I know, `x:foo()` is just a syntactic sugar for `x.foo(self)` but combining this with other classes results in some weird behavior.
Basically, I have two programs

```
y = {}

function y:bar()
    return self.b
end

x = {}

function x:foo()
    return y.bar(self)
end

print(x.foo({b = 3}))
```

This prints `3` as expected

```
y = {}

function y:bar()
    return self.b
end

x = {}

function x:foo()
    return y:bar()
end

print(x.foo({b = 3}))
```

But this prints `nil` !!
I don't understand, why are these two programs printing different things?

Comment: `y:bar()` is the same as `y.bar(y)`

Answer (score 3):

`x:foo()` is syntactic sugar for `x.foo(x)`

which means that

```
function x:foo()
    return y:bar()
end
```

is actually

```
function x:foo()
    return y.bar(y)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

look again at your use of `self`

```
function x:foo()
    return y.bar(self) -- = y.bar(x)
end

function x:foo()
    return y:bar() -- = y.bar(y)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> `x:foo()` is just a syntactic sugar for `x.foo(self)`

This is correct in the context of a function definition but not as an expression.

```
function x.y.z:foo(a, b)
    print(self, a, b)
end
```

is the same as

```
function x.y.z.foo(self, a, b)
    print(self, a, b)
end
```

A [function definition](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.11) being set into a table field can be a method, that is with a `:`. Nested table fields are also allowed, for methods and non-methods, if the keys are strings that are valid Lua identifiers, as in `x.y.z`.

But

```
print(x.y().z:foo(a, b))
```

is the same as

```
local _ = x.y().z
print(_.foo(_, a, b))
```

With the [method call syntax](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.10), the lefthand-side of `:` is an expression (`x.y().z`) that is evaluated only once.